# Can we use the Archetype 22 for AEM version 6.4.2?

Tags: java, maven, adobe, aem, aem-6

Currently, we are in 6.4.2, and we are adding a new repo to the instance. We are planning for the AEM instance upgrade to 6.4.6 or .8 in the future( not yet decided for timeline). 
After building the project, we intended to all core components( because every archetype tied with diff versions- archetype 22 comes with 2.7.0 and my env using 2.5.0) dependencies from the code.

when i compare 2 pom.xml's, archetype 22 is creating extra all folder in the structure 
below are the few differences present in remaining pom.xml files-

```
<plugin>
<groupId>biz.aQute.bnd</groupId>
<artifactId>bnd-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>${bnd.version}</version>
</plugin>

<dependencies>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.sling</groupId>
<artifactId>org.apache.sling.caconfig.bnd-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.0.2</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>

<dependency>
<groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
<artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Can we use archetype 22?

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to update the core components you can do it, Core components are not tied to the Archetype version, but to AEM itself. Check compatibility here: https://github.com/adobe/aem-core-wcm-components/releases

The latest version (2.9.0) works with 6.4.8.

```
       <dependency>
            <groupId>com.adobe.cq</groupId>
            <artifactId>core.wcm.components.all</artifactId>
            <type>zip</type>
            <version>2.9.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

For example, in our project, we are using `2.8.0` with Archetype 14 or 15.